# what is the purpose of bearing attribute of location object?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using this plugin for gps functionality.

https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

I am trying to make sense of the bearing property of location object. It is not clear from the docs. What is the actual purpose of bearing property? Thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bearing means location moving direction angle. 0-360 degree

Comment: So does it mean what direction the person was moving when this point was collected?

Comment: Your GPS bearing is the compass direction from your current position to your intended destination

Comment: in other words does it mean the direction the compass was pointing when the point was collected?

Comment: Yes right. you can get bearing by math calculation from the last location to new location movement